# Firefox addon: Have content script retrieve data stored by addon script (using a context menu if possible)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to build a basic addon which would do that:

- copy the values of a few fields (already filled) on a page (not very
  important which one for now)
- save the value locally
- paste the saved values on a similar form (same fields with same names
  etc) on another page (also not very important which page it is for
  now).

So I thought about using context menus and having

- one item to copy data, which does this:

  - collects the value from the page with jQuery
  - sends then to the addon script for storage
- one item to paste data

  - receives the stored data, sent as data
  - fills the empty fields with the data

The problem that I have is with data types and having the stored data sent to the content script.

Here is what I have so far:

main.js

```
var cm = require("sdk/context-menu");
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");

// The following gave me a 'Message: SyntaxError: missing ; before statement'
// So I guess I cannot set the stored data like this to be reachable all over 
// the addon script...
//   var ss.storage.storedFormData = null;

var copyItem = cm.Item({
      label: "copy",
      data: null
});

// Then here I have 'data is not defined'
var pasteItem = cm.Item({
      label: "paste",
      data: ss.storage.storedFormData
});

var searchMenu = cm.Menu({
      label: "Choose what you want to do",
      contentScriptFile: [
            data.url('jquery-1.11.2.min.js'),
            data.url('content-script.js')
      ],
      onMessage: function (formData) {

          console.log('Storing formData');
          var ss.storage.storedFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);

      },
      items: [copyItem, pasteItem]
});
```

content-script.js

```
self.on("click", function (node, data) {

    if (data === null) {
        // 'data' is null = get data from page
        var formData = new Object();

        // Get elements on page
        formData.element1 = $('input#elementId1').val();
        formData.element2 = $('input#elementId2').val();
        formData.element3 = $('input#elementId3').val();

        // Send data to addon script to be stored
        self.postMessage(formData);

    } else {
        // 'data' is not null, populate the page with data

        // Retrieve the data
        formData = JSON.parse(data);

        // Fill the fields with the data
        $('input#elementId1').val(formData.element1);
        $('input#elementId2').val(formData.element2);
        $('input#elementId3').val(formData.element3);
    }

});
```

Comment: You don't want `var` before `ss.storage.storedFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);`

Comment: Also, `data` is undefined, so add a line like `var data = require("sdk/self").data;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I ran the add-on, after making modifications described in comments.  It pasted the first copied formData in a particular session, throughout the session, even if subsequent values were copied.  The problem is that the value of the simple storage variable `ss` is updated only at start time, and the `value` property of menu item `pasteItem` is initialized when it is created, which is also at start time.  The solution is to replace

```
var ss.storage.storedFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```

with

```
pasteItem.data = ss.storage.storedFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);
```